# Liferay login redirect page loop

Tags: java, loops, redirect, authentication, liferay

We are experiencing an issue with our Liferay Portal 6.0 during logging. When you try to login you might get a blank page with the browser spinning that never resolved. However this does not happens all the time; and it happens with any browser. There are no hooks or custom theme installed. Sometime you might be able to login successfully. This is the url used to connect  *https://xtest.www.transentric.com/agl/ptl/secure*

This is a sample of the logs during this issue:

```
[11-04 09:44:34] [WARN] [jsp:104] /home
[11-04 09:44:34] [WARN] [jsp:104] /home
[11-04 09:44:34] [WARN] [jsp:104] /home
```

Below is the network request paths during login. The URL request that fails and throws in a infinite loop is */agl/ptl/secure/en* . However if I try to use that url (*https://xtest.www.transentric.com/agl/ptl/secure/en*) to connect and login, it works every time, no loop. I know the "en" is added because our local is set to English ("en").

1) /agl/ptl/secure

2) Redirect to agl/ptl/secure/c/portal

3) Redirect to /agl/ptl/secure/web/guest

4) Redirect to /agl/ptl/secure/en   and FAILS. Status: 404. It starts over again and gets into an infinite loop.

Can you please help me understand what is going on and/or how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: did you tried clearing your browser cookies and cache?

Comment: Liferay Version 6.0. Yes, I tried to clear my cache.

Comment: did you used CAS for login?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following steps

1. Assign virtual host xtest.www.transentric.com from Control Panel -> Portal Settings
2. Add the same dns as a property web.server.host=xtest.www.transentric.com
3. In the Portal Settings -> Default Landing Page as "/web/guest/login" or "web/guest/home" (your default landing page after login)